# "You shut down your computer because of a problem." keeps displaying on every boot

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I am using a 13" MacBook Air (late 2013 model) with OS X Mavericks.

Yesterday, my computer hung up and gave me a kernel panic error where it told me in different languages that I needed to restart it. Since that restart, it gives me a notification/warning saying, "*You shut down your computer because of a problem.*" every time I boot it up. I am a Mac Newbie and so dont know what to do. Most articles on the internet deal with what to do when that warning shows up. None of those tell you how to get rid of that warning. My computer is running absolutely fine though.

I also repaired the disk using the OS X Recovery Menu and it said it repaired successfully, but the warning is still there. I don't have a backup for time machine.

Adding the log that I found after logging into the main account:

> Anonymous UUID:       DE2FCFFD-8433-B4A8-0C5E-ACA221D73EE4
>
> Sat Mar 15 03:24:24 2014 panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801b8c5fb7):
>   "pmap_page_protect() " "pmap=0xffffff80280fbd40 pn=0x37a47
>   vaddr=0x600001668000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.90.20/osfmk/i386/pmap_x86_common.c:1336
>   Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff809a4cb8e0 :
>   0xffffff801b822fa9  0xffffff809a4cb960 : 0xffffff801b8c5fb7 
>   0xffffff809a4cba20 : 0xffffff801b8c8697  0xffffff809a4cba40 :
>   0xffffff801b892f4d  0xffffff809a4cba80 : 0xffffff801b893030 
>   0xffffff809a4cbac0 : 0xffffff801b87f542  0xffffff809a4cbc40 :
>   0xffffff801b88475d  0xffffff809a4cbcb0 : 0xffffff801b884061 
>   0xffffff809a4cbd70 : 0xffffff801b884015  0xffffff809a4cbd90 :
>   0xffffff801b81551e  0xffffff809a4cbde0 : 0xffffff801b8158df 
>   0xffffff809a4cbe50 : 0xffffff801b815a3e  0xffffff809a4cbe80 :
>   0xffffff801b81dc33  0xffffff809a4cbef0 : 0xffffff801b81e150 
>   0xffffff809a4cbf70 : 0xffffff801b8c976d  0xffffff809a4cbfb0 :
>   0xffffff801b8f3b46
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: notifyd
>
> Mac OS version: 13C64
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST
>   2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   9FEA8EDC-B629-3ED2-A1A3-6521A1885953 Kernel slide:
>   0x000000001b600000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff801b800000 System model
>   name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 26701041034852 last loaded kext at
>   10721000366361: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr
>   0xffffff7f9d8e9000, size 49152) last unloaded kext at 10784257478296:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7f9d8e9000,
>   size 32768) loaded kexts: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.8
>   org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt    4.3.8 org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB   4.3.8
>   org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv   4.3.8 com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0
>   com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.13
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.2.3f10
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.6.0f1
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim  1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.15
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.0.9d1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess    1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   1.1.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.0
>   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.4d1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 4.26.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight   170.3.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.1.12
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 8.2.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul    8.2.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   3.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver   10.21
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.BootCache   35 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter  404
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub  666.4.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.5.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    3.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 831.21.63
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 670.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS  2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.7 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
>   com.apple.security.quarantine 3 com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.7
>   com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib   2.6.0f1 com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.5fc2
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.14
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.2.3f10
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.8
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.7.0d10
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.6.0f1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.6.0f1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.11d1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 91 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.4.1
>   com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl  3.4.35
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2  98.14
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  3.1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  3.1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   1.4.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.6.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.6.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.6.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 650.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    656.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 170.15
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver  24
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver    245.13
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   660.4.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.6.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  2.0.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   3.2.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 630.35
>   com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b5
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport    24
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController  2.0.34
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   675.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac   2.0.34
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi   2.0.34
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
>   com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    2 com.apple.driver.DiskImages   371.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.9 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread   1
>   com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0
>
> System Profile: Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B07, 2
>   processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f7 Graphics: Intel
>   HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In, 1024 MB Memory
>   Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,
>   0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2
>   GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
>   AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117),
>   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.63) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.3f10
>   13477, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network
>   Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F,
>   121.33 GB USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller Thunderbolt
>   Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6 Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM
>   MBA61.0099.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f7
>   Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In,
>   1024 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,
>   0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2
>   GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
>   AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117),
>   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.63) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.3f10
>   13477, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network
>   Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F,
>   121.33 GB USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller Thunderbolt
>   Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6

Comment: did you try this? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: Yes, and sadly it didnt help.

Comment: Please use code formatting for log output. Quote formatting doesn't preserve line breaks and is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 5):

I use a secondary account for my primary use (friend of mine who is a mac enthusiast suggested me to not to use the admin account for my primary use). So when I logged into the MAIN ADMIN ACCOUNT (that I do not use), I found the notification at the desktop (after the usual warning before the boot), I clicked on REPORT and saw the log (added the log to the main question). After I quit the log and restarted again, voila! No warning now! Back to business as usual.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

> Drag the window to the top most part of your screen and then to bottom couple of times. Your mouse pointer will change from busy to normal. Then you can start by choosing any of the buttons as per your wish.

from link: http://www.hackintosh.zone/forums/topic/5840-install-ok-but-fails-on-2nd-boot/

Answer (score -1):

Run DiskWarrior 5.0 on any 10.4 or up Mac and if your problem is a Kernel Panic it will be fixed.. as only this amazing app can. Check it out. If your a pro using Mac you NEED DiskWarrior, especially if your using huge files, audio/video.